# how can i print my password into three variables

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

Query is as below

```
$query = "SELECT password FROM passwordhistory where userid=? order by id desc limit 3";
$stmt2 = $mysqli->prepare($query);
$stmt2->bind_param('i',$id);
$stmt2->execute();
$res=$stmt2->get_result();

while($row=$res->fetch_object()) {
    foreach($row as $t->password) {
        echo $password[1];
    }
}
```

In the above code I want print password in to three variables. I am not able to do this.

Comment: What do you mean by three variables?

Comment: why on earth would you want to print out a password list?

Answer (score 1):

Change your code to this :

```
$i = 0;
while($row=$res->fetch_object())
{
    foreach($row as $t->password) 
    {
       echo $newPass.$i =  $password[1];
       $i++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use str_split function.

```
foreach($row as $t->password)
{
    $array = str_split($password[1],3);
}
```

Check the manual [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php)